# JPEG image file creation to be recognized by OS

Tags: operating-system, jpeg, encoder

I have applied JPEG baseline compression algorithm by writing each step in matlab. Now, I have the JPEG compresses image data in binary form and the header to be appended. Please tell me how to make a file that would be recognized as JPEG file by OS. Should it be binary file or what is the process.?

Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code, what you expect it to do, and any errors you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to read two thing:

1) The JPEG standard

2) The standard for some file format (e.g., JFIF, EXIF).

You are going to need to have a JPEG file header (see file format standards). You are going to have to create DHT, DQT, SOF, and SOS markets for the compressed data (JPEG standard).

All of the data is in binary format. You have to remember to convert FF values in the compressed data stream to FFFF.

Comment: FF in the entropy coded stream must be replaced by FF00, not FFFF